# Derive a concatenated string union from a tree like structure

Tags: typescript

I have the following type which represents routes in a web app

```
interface IRoute {
  readonly path: string,
  readonly children?: IRoute[]
}
```

Given an `IRoute` type, I'd like to generate a union type which consists of all the possible paths.

Assume this is my sample data:

```
const routes: IRoute = {
  path: '',
  children: [
    {
      path: '/dashboard',
    },
    {
      path: '/settings',
      children: [
        {
          path: '/notifications'
        },
        {
          path: '/profile',
          children: [
            {
              path: '/picture'
            },
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Given an IRoute object, is it possible to derive a union of all possible routes?

```
type AllRoutes = 
 | '/'
 | '/dashboard'
 | '/settings'
 | '/settings/notifications'
 | '/settings/profile'
 | '/settings/profile/picture'
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=32&ssc=84&pln=32&pc=4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICUD2BXSyDeAUMslBHACaYgA2AnsgA5xgAWAXMgM5hSgDmAGmKlyVWgwStgNCmRAB+ThhyQA2gF1CAX0J6E1HqVUQu7FbhQBeAiOZtOAcgD0j4SSky5EEJzUiSIhJgphYOZBcKOC5WACNMOCgKNwDkbXdgoJDQhwjnLggwMAEuFOzkT1l5P1SQrPKSe3CXEEximGAEFmBDR1rg9P7AoeCmp2dGKEwOmggyho9pKp8ahbqR8rG8xk6wbDI+tYGMha0F3XKzgZEtbQBuPWdnZABxYAA3H2Q4EDQsS2QmFiACsIAgwIJkMAuFCwExMFwuMBYrNkGBMMgKNAPig4MhsCAer9pt8aDR4YjkaippYuAo9GA6IwUABBMn-SAwmzEAA+eUOfMi0TiCSSAryBSKJXFLklxRA-C4zlaxQQwG6vV5EsK8sVEymMzmWtlOpK+umMggE12+zmQA)

Comment: For example, [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WylA6m) shows the approach I'd take, but it involved quite a bit of tweaking to account for issues you don't seem to be asking directly about but which need to be fixed before proceeding.  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That does work! I realized my example was flawed in that the concatenated string would result in a double `/`. You caught that correctly in your playground example. If you write it up as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it as an answer. I've edited my question to correct this error

Comment: Okay I'll write up my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to fix some things before we can proceed to write an `IRouteToPaths<T>` type function where

```
type AllRoutes = IRouteToPaths<typeof routes>;
```

produces the following [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of paths:

```
/* type AllRoutes = 
   "" | 
   "/dashboard" | 
   "/settings" | 
   "/settings/notifications" | 
   "/settings/profile" | 
   "/settings/profile/picture" 
*/
```

---

If you explicitly [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the type of `routes` to be `IRoute`, then that's all the compiler will know about `routes` afterward.  Any more specific information about the particular initializer will be lost, along with any hope you might have of extracting a union of paths from `routes`:

```
const routes: IRoute = { ... }

type RootPath = typeof routes.path;
// type RootPath = string // ‍♂️
type RootChildren = typeof routes.children;
// type RootChildren = IRoute[] | undefined // ‍♀️
```

Instead you should let the compiler infer the type of `routes`, and check it against `IRoute` afterward if it's important, perhaps by using the new [`satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator):

```
const routes = { ... } satisfies IRoute;
```

Furthermore, a value like `{path: children: [{path: "a"}, {path: "b"}]` will tend to be inferred as type `{path: string, children: {path: string}[]}`, which has more information than `IRoute`, but still not enough to get that union of paths.  If you want the compiler to keep track of the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `path` properties and subproperties, you should use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const routes = { ... } as const satisfies IRoute;
```

And one last thing: `const` assertions infer [`readonly` tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types), which are *wider* than the corresponding read-write array types on which they're based (that is, `string[] extends readonly string[]` but not vice versa).  In order to avoid obnoxious downcasting or other issues, it will be best if we change `IRoute` so that the `children` property is allowed to be `readonly` as well:

```
interface IRoute {
  readonly path: string,
  readonly children?: readonly IRoute[] 
}
```

---

Okay, now we can write `IRouteToPaths`.  Here's one way:

```
type IRouteToPaths<T extends IRoute> =
  T extends IRoute ? `${T['path']}${"" | (
    T['children'] extends readonly (infer R extends IRoute)[] ? IRouteToPaths<R> : never
  )}` : never
```

This is a [resursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types), where the base case happens if the type argument `T` has no `children`, and the recursive case involves computing `IRouteToPaths` for each element of `children`.

It's a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), so `IRouteToPaths<T1 | T2 | T3>` will be equivalent to `IRouteToPaths<T1> | IRouteToPaths<T2> | IRouteToPaths<T3>`... unions in become unions out; this will come in handy when you want to recurse into `children`; we'll just grab the union of the elements of `children` and pass it to `IRouteToPaths` directly.

What we do is [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) the `"path"` property of `T`, and return a [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) where that path property is prepended to a union of the empty string `""` and `IRouteToPaths<>` for the union of the `children` members if they exist (found by [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) with [an `extends` constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#extends-constraints-on-infer-type-variables)).

---

And that's it.  Let's check that it works:

```
const routes = {
  path: '', children: [
    { path: '/dashboard' },
    {
      path: '/settings', children: [
        { path: '/notifications' },
        {
          path: '/profile', children: [
            { path: '/picture' },
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
} as const satisfies IRoute;

type AllRoutes = IRouteToPaths<typeof routes>
/* type AllRoutes = 
   "" | 
   "/dashboard" | 
   "/settings" | 
   "/settings/notifications" | 
   "/settings/profile" | 
   "/settings/profile/picture" 
*/
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-nisKAV+-yAsAwKghkST9JB6GMphyKojIGLDCh4xoQSGFwZcjDkpSGJEQinJsh8HFciQDLZCkCSZDEXBglwwLFLYWjKoQroAII0DQtYSZ0B6pgsGZWtKb6QFwxaEAYABUar8sg8mKbKYrdP2g7IFZKxrJs2y7AOIZ2QhAhcC5tnTL2VwQDcHkGACQIgmCmReW5-mIVwZFShREU+X5AV3DFKJxeiZIIBSZADoQBkGHkQA)

Comment: TIL about both the real-world utility of the `satifies` keyword and about [extends constraints on `infer` type variables](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#extends-constraints-on-infer-type-variables). FWIW, here was my effort without these luxuries: https://tsplay.dev/wE4E2W

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed write up! You touched on a lot of concepts I'm still new to so definitely 10/10 with the explanations along the way